# Summing prices based on quantity

Tags: javascript

I have appended by data to my panel in the code below which displays all the necessary data.

I am trying to extract the price which is being displayed and multiply by the quantity(the value that will be entered).

The problem is when i `alert` the price like in the code i get NaN although it is a number.

```
$(".container").append(
    '<p id="name">Drug: '+  drug.name + '</p> <p id="price">Drug Price  :  '+drug.price+'</p>

    <input type="text"  onKeyUp="multiply()" id="qty"  name="qty" />

    <p id="total">Total Price  $:'+0+'  </p>');  

function multiply()
{
    a = Number(document.getElementById('qty').value);
    b = Number(document.getElementById('price').value);
    c = a * b;

    document.getElementById('total').value = c;

    alert('this' + b);

}
```

Comment: The element with the ID `price` doesn't appear to have a `value` attribute, you're just giving it content. And I don't know where the `quantity` ID is coming from since it doesn't appear to be in your example.

Comment: @DBS, i just gave it an attribute `value = 1` but it is NaN and i just edited the quantity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element `<p id="price">Drug Price  :  '+drug.price+'</p>` doesn't contain a `value` attribute since it's a paragraph element.

I've swapped over lots of the code to JQuery since you're already using it, and used `data-` attributes to handle the values which lets you store them without having to extract from the elements content.

```js
var drug = {"name":"test", "price":"100"};

// In the appended content, I've added a "data-price" attribute to the price element 
// and a span to the total to make the final print out simpler
$(".container").append(
  '<p id="name">Drug: ' + drug.name + '</p>'+
  '<p id="price" data-price="'+drug.price+'">Drug Price  :  ' + drug.price + '</p>'+
  '<input type="text"  onKeyUp="multiply()" id="qty"  name="qty" />'+
  '<p id="total">Total Price  $:<span></span></p>');

function multiply() { 
  a = Number($('#qty').val());
  // Here we access the data attribute
  b = Number($('#price').data("price"));
  c = a * b;

  // Printing out the final value into the span we added earlier
  $("#total span").text(c);

  alert("Total = " + c);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already using jQuery here is the code:

Use onkeyup="multiply(drug.price, this.value)"

```
function multiply(a,b){
   var c = a * b;
   document.getElementById('total').value = c;
}
```

Please note that id has to be uniqe within the document (You can use class if you have multiple, same elements ) and declare the javaScript variables properly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried your solution but then the function is not working